# Is acceleration relative in classical physics?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, acceleration

If my frame is moving with uniform acceleration and so is another frame, then for me that frame should be stationary,i.e acceleration should be zero.Then why is acceleration considered a relative quantity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, acceleration is not relative in classical physics.

The reason for this is that an observer can always tell what their acceleration is without referring to anything external. All you have to do is drop something and see what happens. If you're not accelerating the dropped object will just hover next to you. If you are accelerating then the dropped object will accelerate away from you.

The acceleration measured in this way is called the [proper acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_acceleration) and is an important concept in general relativity. All observers everywhere will agree on the value of your proper acceleration, making it an absolute not a relative quantity.

Where GR differs from Newtonian physics is that the proper acceleration can be different from the coordinate acceleration. Consider the astronauts in the International Space Station. As many videos have testified those astronauts are weightless and anything they drop just hovers next to them. So their proper acceleration is zero. However from our frame of reference the ISS is whizzing round the Earth at about 7.67 km/sec at a distance from the centre of the earth of 6,776km. That means they have a centripetal acceleration of:

$$ a = \frac{v^2}{r} \approx 8.7 \,\text{m/sec}^2 $$

This is a coordinate acceleration, i.e. the acceleration measured in the coordinates of an observer stationary on the Earth's surface. So we have the situation where the astronauts measure their acceleration to be zero while the ground observers measure a non-zero acceleration. However both observers agree that the astronauts are weightless i.e. that their *proper acceleration* is zero.

Comment: but when i look at a frame which is accelerating with the same acceleration as my frame then wont i say that that frame is stationary?

Comment: @spatialdelusion: but if I were to seal you in a box that you couldn't see out of you'd still know you were accelerating because anything you drop would fall away from you. It's certainly true that the other frame is stationary with relative to you, but that just means both frames are accelerating at the same rate not that acceleration of both frames is zero.